# How to install Webpacker with Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, yarnpkg, webpacker

I'm trying to install Webpacker to be able to launch a Yarn server.  I'm on Rails 5 and the gem is installed.

When I run

```
bundle exec rails webpacker:install
```

I get:

```
>> rails aborted!
Don't know how to build task 'webpacker:install' (see --tasks)
bin/rails:15:in `require'
bin/rails:15:in `<main>'
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

The command doesn't seem to exist.

Comment: Maybe this will hep you > https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47574225/webpacker-installation-issue-in-rails-5

Answer (score 7):

install the [`rails/webpacker`](https://github.com/rails/webpacker#installation) gem as from the documentation I am quoting

> ## Installation
>
> You can either add Webpacker during setup of a new Rails 5.1+ application using new --webpack option:
>
> *Available Rails 5.1+*

```
rails new myapp --webpack
Or add it to your Gemfile:
```

> *Gemfile*
>   gem 'webpacker', '~> 3.0'
>
> *OR if you prefer to use master*

```
gem 'webpacker', git: 'https://github.com/rails/webpacker.git'
and finally, run following to install Webpacker:

bundle
bundle exec rails webpacker:install
```

> *OR (on rails version < 5.0)*

```
bundle exec rake webpacker:install
```

Answer (score 5):

First, add the following to the gemfile:

```
gem "webpacker", "~> 3"
```

Then, bundle install:

```
bundle exec rails webpacker:install
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer by editing it, such that others can learn from it

Answer (score 4):

I was trying to install webpacker and, for me, the solution was a bit different from those listed here.

I was trying `gem install webpacker`, but it doesn't change the Gemfile.

Then I searched for why it doesn't change, and to make it work I had to use:

```
bundle add webpacker
```

After that I used:

```
rails webpacker:install
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure webpacker is installed correctly?

Maybe there is an issue with your use of `bundle exec` try running without it.  You can also try running with the `--tasks` flag to verify if the webpacker tasks are available to use.

Comment: This command is not existing when i'm running `--tasks`. However I installed the gem so what can I do to make this command available ?

Comment: If you run `gem list` is it listed under local gems?